# cloudflare SSL in Full(strict) mode still non-ssl connections

Tags: ssl, heroku, cloudflare

Stack:

- Cloudflare

  - SSL in Full(Strict) mode
  - Always Use SSL is ON
- Heroku

  - Automatic Certificate Management (ACM)

All this seems to work well, except that on the Cloudflare SSL Overview tab, under `Traffic Served Over TLS` 30% is labeled `None (not secure)` I would expect this section to have started to approach zero.

The settings above have been in effect for well over 24 hours.

So, where's all this non-ssl traffic coming from?  Is that just traffic coming in over HTTP that Cloudflare is redirecting to SSL before it gets anywhere else? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very likely that traffic is coming in over HTTP that Cloudflare is redirecting to SSL. When someone first requests the HTTP version of the site that will be handled over HTTP (not HTTPS), which will then redirect to the HTTPS version.

Comment: Is there any documentation that can help prove this supposition?

Comment: @jsharpe Not that I'm aware of. Cloudflare doesn't really give much detail here. You could contact their support to gain more information maybe. But in order to test this theory, you just need to make a standard HTTP call to your site, and not follow any redirects. I think `curl` would be the easiest way to do this to ensure nothing is getting cached or anything. But it wouldn't totally confirm that the 30% HTTP traffic you are seeing is a result of that.